# How to add a package to the XQuery repository?

Tags: rest, curl, basex

I am using cURL to execute commands using the REST interface of BaseX like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8984/rest/?command=repo+list
```

There are also [commands to manage the XQuery module repository](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Repository#Commands). I am especially interested in REPO INSTALL to install a package. Is it somehow possible to execute this command using cURL and the REST interface but without having the package already on the target server? I want to provide the file in the body of the cURL request, similar to adding a resource to a database ([source](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST#Command_Line)) which goes like this:

```
curl -i -X PUT -T "etc/xml/factbook.xml" "http://localhost:8984/rest/factbook"
```

Trying

```
curl -i -X PUT -T "/tmp/foo.xar" http://localhost:8984/rest/?command=repo+install
```

Gives me

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)

No path specified.
```

Adding `-H "Content-Type: application/x-xar"` does not help either.

And replacing PUT with POST gives me

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 09:53:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 46
Server: Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)

"" (Line 1): Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in case of standard modules (replace user/pass/server if needed):

```sh
$ curl http://admin:admin@localhost:8984/rest/?command=repo+install+http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx-1.0.1-doc.xq
```